# How to convert numpy.ndarray to a JSON file using Google Colab?

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-colaboratory, dbf

I have a `dbf` file that I want to convert to a JSON file using Google Colab.

In order to accomplish this task, I am loading the DBF in a `pandas dataframe`, and from there, I am converting to a `numpy.ndarray` and then convert into the final JSON.

These are the first 5 lines of the `pd dataframe` that come from the DBF file:

`print(df)`

```
       CD_MUN                 NM_MUN SIGLA_UF  AREA_KM2
0     1100015  Alta Floresta D'Oeste       RO  7067.127
1     1100023              Ariquemes       RO  4426.571
2     1100031                 Cabixi       RO  1314.352
3     1100049                 Cacoal       RO  3793.000
4     1100056             Cerejeiras       RO  2783.300
```

These are the first lines of the `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`:

`print(dfValues)`

```
[['1100015' "Alta Floresta D'Oeste" 'RO' 7067.127]
 ['1100023' 'Ariquemes' 'RO' 4426.571]
 ['1100031' 'Cabixi' 'RO' 1314.352]
 ...
 ['5222203' 'Vila Boa' 'GO' 1060.172]
 ['5222302' 'Vila Propício' 'GO' 2181.583]
 ['5300108' 'Brasília' 'DF' 5760.784]]
```

I would like to have a JSON like the following structure:

```json
{[
   {"CD_MUN":"1100015","NM_MUN":"Cabixi","SIGLA_UF":"RO"},
   {"CD_MUN":"1100049","NM_MUN":"Cacoal","SIGLA_UF":"RO"},
   ...
]}
```

This is what I have so far, but I am blocked:

```py
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5
import json
from json import JSONEncoder
import numpy


dbfPath = 'BR_Municipios_2020.dbf'

df = Dbf5(dbfPath).to_dataframe()
# print(df)

dfValues = df.values
print(dfValues)
print(type(dfValues))

# dfJSON = dfValues.to_json()
# print(dfJSON)

# Iterate and create the JSON
# for index, row in df.iterrows():
#     print(row['CD_MUN'])

# Create a JSON file. Working
# with open('BR_Municipios_2020.json', 'a') as testwritefile:
#     testwritefile.write(dfJSON)
```

Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this task without iterating through this array and creating the JSON.

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='records')`, then dump it to json. You can also use [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html): `df.to_json(orient='records')`.

Comment: Your way is faster. I added your notes in the code. Thanks

Comment: do you have an idea to fix the unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

I did find the way:

```
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5
import json
import numpy


dbfPath = 'BR_Municipios_2020.dbf'

# Create a 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' from the DBF
df = Dbf5(dbfPath).to_dataframe()
# print (type(df)) # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# print (df)
# print ('-----') 

# Get an array of values from the 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' object
dfValues = df.values
# print (type(dfValues)) #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
# print (dfValues)
# print ('-----') 

# Convert the 'numpy.ndarray' into a <class 'list'>
lists = dfValues.tolist()
# print (type(lists)) # <class 'list'>
# print (lists)
# print ('-----')

# Traverse the <class 'list'> and recreate a new one
GIS_list = [{'CD_MUN': x[0], 'NM_MUN': x[1], 'SIGLA_UF': x[2]} for i, x in enumerate(lists)]
# print (type(GIS_list)) # <class 'list'>
# print(GIS_list) # [{'CD_MUN': '1100015', 'NM_MUN': "Alta Floresta D'Oeste", 'SIGLA_UF': 'RO'}, {'CD_MUN': '1100023',
# print ('-----')

# Convert the GIS_list into GIS_br_JSON
GIS_br_JSON = json.dumps(GIS_list)
# print (type(GIS_br_JSON)) # <class 'str'>
# print (GIS_br_JSON)
# print ('-----')

# Save the JSON in a file
with open('BR_Municipios_2020.json', 'a') as testwritefile:
    testwritefile.write(GIS_br_JSON)
print ('JSON exported')


# Faster way after Quang Hoang comments
dfDic = df.to_dict(orient='records')
# print (type(dfDic)) # <class 'list'>
# print (dfDic)
# print ('-----') 

GIS_br_JSON2 = json.dumps(dfDic)
#print (type(GIS_br_JSON2)) # <class 'str'>
#print (GIS_br_JSON2)
#print ('-----')

# Save the JSON in a file
with open('BR_Municipios_2020.json', 'a') as testwritefile:
    testwritefile.write(GIS_br_JSON2)
print ('JSON exported')
```

And this is the output in the JSON validator:
[image]

Faster way after @Quang Hoang comments:
[image]

The other issue now is to fix these weird character: `Guajar\u00e1-Mirim`